# URL rewrite rule is not working in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i am using godaddy hosting and addon domain. i want to make my long url to short url.

for example my url is follwing:
www.example.com/events/landing_event.php?url=text-first

and i want following url:
www.example.com/events/text-first

for this i am using following rewrite url in .htaccess file

> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ events/landing_event.php?url=$1 [L]
>
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ events/landing_event.php?url=$1 [L]

but this rewrite rule is not working.
so please help how can i make short url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this source after you make sure `RewriteEngine Enabled` and `On`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^events/([^/]*)$ /events/landing_event.php?url=$1 [L]
```

The original URL:
http://www.example.com/events/landing_event.php?url=text-first

The rewritten URL:
http://www.example.com/events/text-first

Updated with 500 Internal Server Error

> Your code is guaranteed to generate 500 internal server error because it is causing infinite looping. Reason is that your matching URI pattern is: ^events/([^/]*)$
>
> Which matches your URLs before and after rewrites. And once it reaches max allowed internal rewrite limit Apache throws 500 internal server error and bails out.

Change your code to this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^events/([^/]*)$ /events/landing_event.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: it is showing 500 errror, i am using shared hosting for my domain.

Comment: @Quynh i tried your code and getting following error:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@example.santosh.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: now, no error is showing but nothing happens.. means same url showing. one more point want to add may be important, i am using subdirectroy of domain where i want to use url like i have main domain is test.com, in text.com i have created my website example.com where i want to use rewrite.

Comment: @SantoshKhatri And now it's working or not bro. It will working same with sub domain. Just write new same .htaccess and put to exact directory.

Comment: @QuynhNguyen - no it is not working. nothing happens.

Comment: @SantoshKhatri Your system is apache or nginx server?

Comment: @QuynhNguyen - apache bro

Comment: @SantoshKhatri Are you try updated code for .htaccess. ==> `RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  .......`

Comment: @QuynhNguyen - Yes bro, even i have addet this "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d" as i am using godaddy hosting.

Comment: @QuynhNguyen - thanks bro, it is working now, you save my life.

Comment: @QuynhNguyen - Please help me, i have another link like below:

www.example.com/news/landing_news.php?url=text-first

and i implement this rule : 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*)$ /news/landing_news.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

now the issue is this redirect to my below link:

www.example.com/events/text-first

so where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved me :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /events/landing_event.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Add this in your .htaccess file

Comment: showing 500 error, i am using shared hosting server so may this effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can see there are many ways to achieve that goal.

Also

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^events/([^/]*)\.html$ /events/landing_event.php?url=$1 [L]
```

would do the job. So basicly, how does the full scope of your project urls look like?

Like do you always want to print the parameters? If yes, also the name sometimes or also the value?

Comment: showing 500 error, i am using shared hosting server so might be effect this or not?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the spec of the hosters server.

Anyhow, you can use this to check and generate: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

Answer (score 0):

The newer versions of apache requires you to change AllowOverride on /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

from

```
    AllowOverride None
```

to

```
    AllowOverride All
```